# RecyclerView shuffling items images

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android and I wanted to create a chat in my app, it's like a global roomchat based on firebase. Messages are displayed via RecyclerView and the problem is that when it's loaded the images of people, their names are somehow mixed up. When I go back to previous activity and open the chat activity again everything becomes OK. But the when a new message is added the rows shuffle again. I'm sure that it should be very ease to fix, but I can't...Please help. Thank you!

---

This is the chat activity oncreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_chat);


    main_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
    main_recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {


        mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    }
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null) {

        sendToStart();

    } else {

        mUserRef.child("online").setValue("true");
        String transp = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chatqs-a4c10.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Ftransp.png?alt=media&token=fc7b2315-f24b-453a-926e-364fff55e31b";
        mUserRef.child("version").setValue(transp);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.chattb);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.chat_title);

        imageButton_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chat_send_btn);
        editText_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_message_view);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseRef = database.getReference();
        mContext = (MainChatPage.this);

        adapter = new MainAdapter(mContext, messageArrayList);
        main_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);


        main_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));

        databaseRef.child("the_messages").limitToLast(50).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                main_recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final Message new_message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);

                final String userid = dataSnapshot.child("userID").getValue().toString();

                mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                final String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();
                mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid).child("blocked");
                mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(userid).exists()) {

                            messageArrayList.remove(new_message);

                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                main_recycler_view.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                messageArrayList.add(new_message);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });
```

---

My adapter:

```
public MainAdapter(MainChatPage context, ArrayList<Message> data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_single_layout, null);
    message_profile_layout = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_profile_layout);

    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {

    final Message message = data.get(i);
    final String userid = message.getUserID();
    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    final String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid).child("blocked");
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid);
            mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    String thumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
                    String nome = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String dialog_name = nome;
                    String vers = dataSnapshot.child("version").getValue().toString();
                    //String proic = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chatqs-a4c10.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Ficonfinder-pro-icon-icon.png?alt=media&token=1ca05e32-f3e7-4f73-af54-2be17ad0fed6";

                //    Picasso.with(myViewHolder.mes_proicon.getContext()).load(proic)
                //            .placeholder(R.drawable.transp).into(myViewHolder.mes_proicon);
                //                        myViewHolder.name_text_layout.setText(nome);
                    Picasso.with(myViewHolder.message_profile_layout.getContext()).load(thumb)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(myViewHolder.message_profile_layout);
                    Picasso.with(myViewHolder.mes_proicon.getContext()).load(vers)
                               .placeholder(R.drawable.transp).into(myViewHolder.mes_proicon);
                                            myViewHolder.name_text_layout.setText(nome);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
            String formatted_date = SCUtils.formatted_date(message.getTimestamp());


            myViewHolder.message_text_layout.setText(Html.fromHtml(message.getMessage()));

            myViewHolder.time_text_layout.setText(Html.fromHtml(formatted_date));

            myViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (!userid.equals(current_uid)) {


                        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

                        LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
                        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                        TextView dialog_name = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_name);
                        CircleImageView dialog_icon = (CircleImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_icon);

                        builder.setView(dialogView);
                        dialog_name.setText(myViewHolder.name_text_layout.getText());
                        dialog_icon.setImageDrawable(myViewHolder.message_profile_layout.getDrawable());

                        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.block, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid).child("blocked");
                                mDatabase.child(userid).push().setValue("");
                            }
                        })
                                .setNegativeButton(R.string.open_profile, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        Intent chatIntent = new Intent(mContext, UserProfileActivity.class);
                                        chatIntent.putExtra("user_id", userid);

                                        mContext.startActivity(chatIntent);
                                        mContext.finish();
                                    }
                                });

                       builder.show();

                    } else {
                        Intent Intent = new Intent(mContext, ProfileFragment.class);

                        mContext.startActivity(Intent);
                        mContext.finish();
                    }
                }

            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
```

}
  public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

```
  View mView;



  protected TextView message_text_layout;
protected TextView name_text_layout;
protected TextView time_text_layout;

    protected CircleImageView message_profile_layout;
protected CircleImageView mes_proicon;


public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mView = itemView;


  this.message_text_layout = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.message_text_layout);
  this.name_text_layout = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_layout);
  this.time_text_layout = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.time_text_layout);
  this.mes_proicon = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.mes_proicon);


  this.message_profile_layout = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.message_profile_layout);


}
}
```

Comment: I think that the reason for the wrong image and username is in my onbindviewholder in the adapter, because messages' texts and timestapms do not mix and they are loaded after ondatachanged

Answer (score 0):

just remove .placeholder. I dont know why but sometimes it happens because of this method

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't help, the problem is the same, mixing up items' images and name_text_layout Textviews